# Listview selection rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the selection border on a ListViewItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691726/how-can-i-remove-the-selection-border-on-a-listviewitem)

I'm using the following code to make a Listview to use windows 7 native look and to prevent flickering.

[Windows 7 Native Look for .NET ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086682/windows-7-native-look-for-net-listview)

http://geekswithblogs.net/CPound/archive/2006/02/27/70834.aspx

But I'm still getting a black dotted selection rectangle.

[image: dotted]

[image: explorer]

The question will be... How can I achieve the explorer selection rectangle?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment in the link provided by AVIDeveloper.

> While the ShowFocusCues itself didn't work, the WM_CHANGEUISTATE
>   listed on that MSDN page led me to the right answer. By sending a
>   WM_CHANGEUISTATE message with UISF_HIDEFOCUS I was able to get rid of
>   the focus rectangle. – Telanor Apr 22 '10 at 17:11

I tried to find some information about this messages and eventualy saw this post: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/128345-listview-remove-focuscues.html#post958690

So, we need to send the WM_CHANGEUISTATE message to the ListView in the constructor

```
SendMessage(Handle, 0x127, 0x10001, 0);
```

And we are only going to override the OnSelectedIndexChanged and OnEnter events.

```
protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    SendMessage(Handle, 0x127, 0x10001, 0);
}
protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnEnter(e);
    SendMessage(Handle, 0x127, 0x10001, 0);
}
```

Without overriding the OnEnter event, the same black dotted selection rectangle will appear when the ListView gets the focus.

I tried to explain the best I could since I'm not a fluent English speaker and I'm going to wait if someone has a better answer before accepting mine.